# Is it possible to use mongoid "nested attributes" from belongs_to side of one-to-many relation?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

Is it possible to use mongoid "[nested attributes](http://mongoid.org/docs/relations/nested_attributes.html)" from belongs_to side of one-to-one relation?

Example:

```
class Bar1
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :bar2

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bar2
end
```

When Im trying to access nested attributes I get following exception: NoMethodError: undefined method `bar2_attributes'

My primary aim is to use "Nested Attributes" feature for caching of referenced document properties.

What Im doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have read docs again and now understand that "netsted attributes" is used for saving data. And cannot be used for caching of referenced document.

Answer (score 1):

You might be trying to access it as a method like `Class.attr` when you should be using the array access method: `class['attr']`. My Guess is that even if it isn't a dynamic field that the rules still apply as it's nested and probably doesn't yet exist.

## From the mongoid docs

> By default Mongoid supports dynamic fields - that is it will allow attributes to get set and persisted on the document even if a field was not defined for them. There is a slight 'gotcha' however when dealing with dynamic attributes in that Mongoid is not completely lenient about the use of method_missing and breaking the public interface of the Document class.
>   When dealing with dynamic attributes the following rules apply:
>   If the attribute exists in the document, Mongoid will provide you with your standard getter and setter methods. For example, consider a person who has an attribute of "gender" set on the document:

## Set the person's gender to male.

```
person[:gender] = "Male"
person.gender = "Male"
```

## Get the person's gender.

```
person.gender
```

If the attribute does not already exist on the document, Mongoid will not provide you with the getters and setters and will enforce normal method_missing behavior. In this case you must use the other provided accessor methods: ([] and []=) or (read_attribute and write_attribute).

## Raise a NoMethodError if value isn't set.

```
person.gender
person.gender = "Male"
```

## Retrieve a dynamic field safely.

```
person[:gender]
person.read_attribute(:gender)
```

## Write a dynamic field safely.

```
person[:gender] = "Male"
person.write_attribute(:gender, "Male")
```

Dynamic attributes can be completely turned off by setting the Mongoid configuration option allow_dynamic_fields to false.

Comment: Are you talking about "Nested Attributes" feature? I think you haven't understand me.

Comment: No, I got you. I think it's related. Try accessing them via the [] method.

Comment: I have read docs again and now understand that "netsted attributes" is used for saving data. And cannot be used for caching of referenced document.